# Firebase serve is serving an old version of my project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have a react application which I want to host using firebase. I managed to deploy the front end no problem. I then went to add firebase functions to the project. However when I run firebase serve, it serves an old version of the project to localhost:5000.

I've tried uninstalling and removing all firebase files from the project. Deleting the project from firebase. Rebuilding the application with npm run build and redeploying the project.

Also it deploys the most recent version correctly when I use firebase deploy but still serves the outdated version in the localhost (including files which are completely deleted from the project)

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated as i'm completely stumped.

Thanks

Comment: hmm, if it 's serving old stuff - specifically when running locally, seems like it may be a strange caching issue.  May seem obvious, but have you done a hard refresh or try incognito browser to confirm no caching is taking place before diagnosing further?

Comment: I checked it in different browsers and using icognito. It doesn't actually serve anything under those conditions. Just a blank page. I must be doing something completely wrong! But i'm assuming that the old version is a cache issue based on this.

Comment: yeah, that does seem like a caching thing.  Were you able to serve the project  locally without problems (as in, you could make a change and then see your change) before you added the firebase function stuff?

Comment: Yes I was. It still worked fine using npm start. Thanks mate. Didn't think to check cache!

Comment: nice, way to stick with it and figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

The issue was cache. Clearing cache or using a different browser seems to solve the problem.